# Student Database with linked lists

Tags: java, database, sorting, linked-list

I am still a pretty novice programmer so please be as descriptive as possible. I'm having issues getting all my code working for my assignment. The assignment gives me four complete files that do not need changed(StudentIf.java StudentCollectionIf.java StudentLLNode.java and StudentRecords.java) and a test text file with a list of names an ID and five grades.

Link to Assignment Instructions:
https://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs161/Fall14/more_assignments/P5/P5.html

The two files that I have modified are Student.java and StudentLL.java
Also in my Run Configuration-Arguments I have "cs161 5"
I know its a lot but any help would be fantastic.

I am currently getting this output:(Top Score and Avg Score are not implemented yet)

```
Course cs161: 5 grades
Top Score: 10.0
Avg Score: 10.0
Course: null
null    0   score: 81.00
```

What should be produced

```
Course cs161: 5 grades
Top Score: 90.0
Ave Score: 76.16
Course: cs161
Jim     1234  50 40 50 60 70    score: 54.00
John    1243  60 70 80 55 55    score: 64.00
Mick    1324  70 60 70 80 90    score: 74.00
Mike    1342  60 70 80 90 99    score: 79.80
Lena    1423  99 50 90 90 85    score: 82.80
Leila   1432  60 70 60 70 60    score: 64.00
Ada     2134  90 90 90 90 90    score: 90.00
Adam    2143  85 95 85 75 65    score: 81.00
Helen   2314  89 79 99 89 88    score: 88.80
Ellen   2341  90 95 88 77 66    score: 83.20
```

My code for Student.java and StudentLL.java

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Student implements StudentIF{



    private String name;
    private int id;
    private int[] grades;
    private int numGrades;
    private int totalGrades;

    // The constructor
    //    initializes the instance variables  
    //    name, id, grades = new int[totalGrades], and numGrades = 0;
    public Student (String name, int id, int totalGrades){
        name = this.getName();
        id = this.getId();
        grades = new int[totalGrades];
        numGrades= 0;

       //System.out.println(name+"  "+id+"   "+grades[0]+" "+grades[1]+" "+grades[2]+" "+grades[3]+" "+grades[4]+" "+"   "+totalGrades);
    }

    public String toString() {
        String res = name + "\t" + id + " ";
        for (int i=0; i < totalGrades; i++) {
            res += " " + grades[i];
        }
        res += "\tscore: " + new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(computeScore());
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(StudentIF arg0) {
        if (arg0 == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (this.id > arg0.getId())
            return 1;
        else if (this.id < arg0.getId())
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public double computeScore() {
        double total = 0;
          if (numGrades == 0) {
            return total;
          }
          if (numGrades > grades.length) {
            numGrades = grades.length;
          }
          for (int i = 0; i < numGrades; i++) {
            total += grades[i];
          }
          return total / numGrades;
        //return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addGrade(int newGrade) {
        if(numGrades<grades.length){
            grades[numGrades] = newGrade;
            numGrades++;
           // System.out.println(grades[0]+" "+grades[1]+" "+grades[2]+" "+grades[3]+" "+grades[4]);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(StudentIF other) {
        if (other.getId() == this.getId()) {
            return true;
          }
          return false;
    }

}
```

========

```
public class StudentLL implements StudentCollectionIF{
    private String course;
    private StudentLLNode head;
    private int size;
    private boolean debug;  // you can set debug in main

    // the client code provides the course name
    public StudentLL(String course){
        course = this.course;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String res = "Course: " + course + "\n";
        for(StudentLLNode curr = head; curr !=null; curr=curr.getNext()){
             StudentIF nS = curr.getStd();
             res = res + nS + "\n";
        }
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean insort(StudentIF s) {
        StudentLLNode curr = head;

        if (s == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (head == null) {
            StudentLLNode student = new StudentLLNode(s);
            head = student;
            size++;
            //System.out.println("working");
            return true;
        } else {
            if (curr.getStd().compareTo(s) == 0) {
                //System.out.println("working");
                return false;
            }
            while (curr.getNext() != null) {
                if(s.compareTo(curr.getStd()) == 1){
                    //c
                }
                curr = curr.getNext();
            }
            //c
            StudentLLNode student1 = new StudentLLNode(s);
            curr.setNext(student1);
            size++;
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(StudentIF s) {
        StudentLLNode current = head;
        if(s == null){
            return false;
        }
        if(s.getId() == (head.getStd().getId())){
            //StudentLLNode  top = head;
            head = head.getNext();
            size--;
            return true;
        }
        else{
            StudentLLNode previous, next;
            previous = current;
            current = current.getNext();
            while(current != null){
               next = current.getNext();
               if(s.getId() == (current.getStd().getId())){  
                    previous.setNext(next); //doesn't matter if next is null or not
                    size--;
                    return true;
                }
               previous = current;
               current = next;
            }
        }
        return false;
      }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public double classAvg() {
        //double total = 0.0;
        //for (int i=0; i<this.size(); i++) {
        //  total += grades[i];
        //}
        //return total / grades.length;
        return 10;
    }

    @Override
    public double classTopScore() {

        return 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some huge misunderstandings, I will point to some of those. 
First I noticed you don't create your constructors properly. 
In the class Student your constructor should be like:

```
public Student (String name, int id, int totalGrades){
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    grades = new int[totalGrades];
    this.totalGrades = totalGrades;
    numGrades= 0;
}
```

So here you say this.name = name and not the other way around. If you write name=this.name you are setting the value of the constructor variable name to the value of the Student's object variable name;
When you write this.name you are referring to the object variable name, but when you write only name you are referring to the local variable name that is created in the constructor.
Also I suggest you write your get methods like this:

```
public String getName()
{
     return this.name;
}
```

By writing return this.name you make it clear that you return the object's name variable.

You are doing the same mistake with the StudentLL constructor. You are saying that the constructor's local variable course is going to get the value of your object's course variable. So that constructor should be like this:

```
public StudentLL(String theCourseValue)
{
     this.course = theCourseValue;
}
```

Notice I named the constructor parameter variable theCourseValue to show you that it doesn't matter how you name the local variable in your constructor. In this case you could also write course = theCourseValue (without the THIS keyword) because the only variable with the name course that constructor can see is the object's course variable.

One other thing I noticed is the way you compare the student nodes. You use

```
  if(s.getId() == (current.getStd().getId()))
```

which is not wrong but you have a special method just for that in your Student class. It's the equals method. This is the way you use it and id does exactly the same thing:

```
if(s.equals(current.getStd()))
```

I hope this gives you some directions. And I strongly suggest you to read some more about the constructors because I see that you have missed some important concepts about the role of the constructors and how they work.

Comment: This was a ton of help thank you! Its printing out everything i need it to without duplicates which is great. But it is not sorting by the ID, any suggestions on that section?

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is where you are supposed to *initialize* your object fields. You seem to be reading them instead of setting values in them.

```
public Student (String name, int id, int totalGrades){
     name = this.getName();
     id = this.getId();
```

Here you are taking the as-yet empty value of your name fields and assigning it to the name **parameter** which is going to be discarded anyway. Instead, you should use:

```
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
```

Here:

```
    grades = new int[totalGrades];
```

You are creating the array properly, but you are not keeping your totalGrades variable in your fields, so when the time comes to use it in printing, it is zero. So:

```
    this.totalGrades = totalGrades;
```

The same should be done in your other constructor. It is for setting values, not for reading them. Your assignment is reversed. The left hand variable is receiving the value on the right, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the full solution but a couple of things that stick out for me:

In **insort()**

```
// Is it clear that you should ignore a student with the 
// same id or should you overwrite ?
if (curr.getStd().compareTo(s) == 0) {
  // curr.setStd(s); ?
  return false;
}

// You iterate over the full list and compare
// to your new node. But never break based 
// in this comparison. Furthermore you have
// to iterate until the new node is **smaller**
// then the current one and insert **before** it  

StudentLLNode prev=null; // The node before the current node
while (curr != null) {
  // If we e.g. we have a list [5,7,9,12] and want to insert
  // 8 we iterate until we hit 9 and insert **before** 9

  if(s.compareTo(curr.getStd()) == 0){
     return false;           // should we overwrite ?
  }

  if(s.compareTo(curr.getStd()) == -1){
     break;           //c
  }
  // prev always refers to the node of the previous iteration
  // in our example #7 when we break
  prev = curr;
  curr = curr.getNext();
}

StudentLLNode student1 = new StudentLLNode(s);

// If prev is still null then the very first 
// node eas bigger then the new one and we have
// to insert before head

if(prev==null) {
   student1.setNext(head);
   head = student1;
 } else {
   student1.setNext(prev.getNext());
   prev.setNext(student1);
 }
```

In **remove**
This

```
if(s.getId() == (head.getStd().getId())){
 //StudentLLNode  top = head;
 head = head.getNext();
 size--;
 return true;
}
```

Will give you a NullPointerException if no one ever inserted anything into the list

EDIT: More comments and identification of identical IDs in while loop...

Comment: And I totaly missed that you only compare the very first node for the identical ID. You'll have to move it into the while loop as well. So the comparision would be .compareTo(...)<=0 and a special treatment if the ID is the same.

Comment: I don't really understand, it might be because iv been programming for a long time today but could explain your code in more detail? I tried to implement your code and replaced curr with head and then on the 2nd to last line i assume pref.setNext is supoosed to be prev.setNext? But when I execute it, it is only giving me Helens info and thats all. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Damoclyes Added more comments. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ohh ok I think I understand now. Two things though, in the first if statement is your comment saying it should be curr.getStd(s)? Then is curr supposed to changed with head? Eclipse is giving me errors on all the curr's.

Comment: @Damoclyes no i meant setStd(s), In case you want to overwrite students with the same id. but i don't know if this is demanded by the assignment. Your original code kind of looked like it only wanted to return false, although it never compared the whole list for equality, only the first node. I haven't compile any of this. Take it as pseudo code that only resembles JAVA...